# ##[error]Error: /usr/local/bin/openssl failed with return code: - Azure devops - Xamarin iOS

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios

I am getting this error when I create and run my pipeline in YAML. I could able to successfully run my pipeline which I created in the classic editor.

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: ******-****-****-****-*********
    certPwd: ''
    setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false
```

For certSecureFile, I tried with both security file codes and also tried giving its name (AFP_Distribution_Certificate.p12). But ended up getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us, the `certSecureFile` is the `Name` attribute in  Secure Files (you can rename it in secure files).

In our YAML pipeline for iOS build it looks like this:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: ${{parameters.certSecureFile}}
    certPwd: ${{parameters.certPwd}}
    keychain: 'temp'
```

The parameters are:

`certSecureFile` is the "Name" of the secure file in the Library / Secure files area.

This secure file is a `.p12` file - it's the *private key* exported from Keychain Access, after importing the `.cer` file downloaded from Apple.  (Looks like yours is too).

Our "update the certificate" documentation has specific instructions about making sure the certificate has the same name - we rename the previous certificate and naming the new one with "the" name.  Something like `myapp_certificate.p12` but it can be anything.

The `certPwd` parameter comes from a credentials group stored via Library / Variable groups. It's got to match the password you used when you exported it from Keychain access. Strongly recommend you don't continue to use `''`

I don't know where our `keychain: temp` came from, but I doubt that's related to openSSL.

(If you haven't resolved this already, it'd probably be worth putting the full error message in the body of the question too)